# Vertical representation of Euclid's algorithm

Tags: math-mode, xetex, tabularx, tikz-styles, displaystyle

I want to show how to find the gcd(greatest common divisor) of 299 and 247 :
[image]

But how can I get this ?tabular?Thx for your kind reply.....

Comment: Tabular or array, depending on whether you're in text or math mode. However, I must say, what is performed is not very clear to me.

Comment: Do you mean programmatically or do you just want to replicate that table?

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of the numbers?

Comment: @projetmbc https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithme_d%27Euclide#Exemple

Comment: I was talking about the numbers outside the table.

Answer (score 3):

It is not entirely clear what is your problem. If like to have the LaTeX code, which reproduce shoved image, than try try following:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
1   &   299 &   247 &   4   \\
    &   247 &   208 &       \\
    \cline{2-3}
1   &   52  &   39  &   3   \\
    &   39  &   39  &       \\
    \cline{2-3}
    &   13  &       &       
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]